# ProcessException: Process exited abnormally: Starting: Intent {...MainActivity (has extras) }

Tags: android, flutter

Unable to install app in Android 12 but it is working in android 11 after i updated target sdk to 31.
I have added andriod:exported to all the activites which uses intent filter after that if i run the app. it gives the below error.
not sure about the error what it is saying how can i fix it. please check

```
    ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x20000000 cmp= ..package name here.. .MainActivity (has extras) }


Exception occurred while executing 'start':
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x30000000 cmp=...package name here.. .MainActivity (has extras) } from null (pid=7644, uid=2000) not exported from uid 11272
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission(ActivityTaskSupervisor.java:1335)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.executeRequest(ActivityStarter.java:1252)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:883)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1871)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1742)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUserWithFeature(ActivityManagerService.java:3543)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.runStartActivity(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:596)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.onCommand(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:201)
    at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onShellCommand(ActivityManagerService.java:10429)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:986)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:860)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:6049)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3034)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1220)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1179)
  Command: /Users/flipitnews/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s RZ8M22CVXEF shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x20000000 --ez enable-dart-profiling true com.flipitnews.finance/com.flipitnews.finance.flipitnews_flutter_app.MainActivity
#0      RunResult.throwException (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:123:5)
#1      _DefaultProcessUtils.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:275:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      AndroidDevice.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:677:28)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FlutterDevice.runCold (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:504:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      ColdRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_cold.dart:57:28)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      AppDomain.launch.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:641:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      AppDomain.launch (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:639:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:596:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1209:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 3):

I opened my android folder separately, then moved to AndroidMainifest file
Android Studio suggest to set this to true in .MainActivity  activity tag

```
android:exported="true"
```